# after upgrade to winbind 3.6.24 the NT users cannot login into my RHEL4 box

Tags: linux, samba, winbind, rhel4

I upgraded winbind/samba from 3.0.33 to 3.6.24 in a 32-bit RHEL4 box.

The problem now is that any NT user cannot login. The error message found in /var/log/messages is

```
Sep  3 09:05:20 node2 sshd[7209]: pam_winbind(sshd): request wbcLogonUser failed: WBC_ERR_AUTH_ERROR, PAM error: PAM_AUTH_ERR (7), NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD, Error message was: Wrong Password
Sep  3 09:05:20 node2 sshd[7209]: pam_winbind(sshd): user 'user2' denied access (incorrect password or invalid membership)
```

The wbinfo command suggests everything is OK:

```
# wbinfo -t
checking the trust secret for domain MYDOMAIN via RPC calls succeeded
# wbinfo -a user2%mypassword
plaintext password authentication succeeded
challenge/response password authentication succeeded
# wbinfo -K user2%mypassword
plaintext kerberos password authentication for [user2%mypassword] succeeded (requesting cctype: FILE)
credentials were put in: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
```

I guess there is no problem with the NT user because this user 'user2' logins successfully in other 32-bit RHEL4 with samba 3.0.33 not upgraded yet.

Thanx in advance

```
UPDATE 1
```

I realized that the user2 can login in the system from the console and using a FTP client. Therefore, SSH is the only way the user2 cannot login.

I found an "AllowGroups" directive in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
AllowGroups root MYusers
```

When I comment out that directive, the user2 logins succesfully.

```
UPDATE 2
```

Finally, after a lot of trials, I realized that the winbind 3.6.24 show NT group names in lowercase, not keeping the original case of every group name characters:

```
$ id
uid=10000(user2) gid=10000(myusers)
```

In other box using winbind 3.0.33:

```
$ id
uid=10009(user2) gid=10006(MYusers)
```

Then I changed the AllowGroups directive in the sshd_config file:

```
AllowGroups root myusers
```

and restarted the sshd. Then user2 can login succesfully by means of SSH.

Maybe a new winbind parameter to convert the case?
Maybe a bug?